# this.setState Not working for my React native Project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

On my react native app which i am developing this.setState is not working and not updating the value  in the constructor . but this.state({}) is working. but when i am using that it is reseting the constructor  Anyone please point what is wrong in this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
import { RkTextInput, RkButton } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            uType: 'normal',
            AdminNavbutton: ''
        }
    }

    ProfileSubmithandler = () => {
        alert(this.state.uType + " " + this.state.AdminNavbutton)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.readUserData();
    }

    readUserData = () => {
        userstype = 'users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType'

        firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => {
            this.setState({ uType: snapshot.val() }) // notworking and not updating uType
            alert(snapshot.val()) //working Properly
        })

    }

    emailid = () => {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.titleText}>Taams</Text>
                <Text style={styles.edition}>Developer's Edition</Text>
                <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home</Text>
                <Text>Alpha 0.0.0.1</Text>
                <RkButton onPress={() => this.ProfileSubmithandler()}>
                    <Text style={styles.LoginButtonText}>Submit</Text>
                </RkButton>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(this.state.AdminNavbutton)}><Text style={styles.signinButton}>Profile</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState()` is asynchronous, your updated value will now be available right after calling it.

When `setState()` is done updating your value, you will be able to access the updated data in your `render` function under `this.state.uType`.

If you wan to use your value right away in your function, you should put it in an other variable :

```
readUserData = () => {
    userstype = 'users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType'

    firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => {
        const uType = snapshot.val()
        this.setState({ uType }) // notworking and not updating uType
        alert(snapshot.val()) //working Properly
        alert(uType) // Also working
    })

}
```

Comment: `setState` provides callback as the second argument, in case you want to check value in state after the state is updated.

Comment: Sure, this is another alternative.

Comment: @Treycos  and also upgraded my React and React native versions

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare a variable for "userstype" - line 25

Comment: Upgraded my React and React native versions that fixed my problems

Answer (score 0):

It is because of asyncrouse problem in setSate. Let the button shown when the data extracted from firebase and states becomes set. Here you are:

```
           import React from 'react';
                    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
                    import {RkTextInput, RkButton } from 'react-native-ui-kitten';
                    import * as firebase from 'firebase';



                    export default class Home extends React.Component {
                      constructor(props){
                        super(props)

                        this.state={
                          uType:'normal',
                          AdminNavbutton:false,
                        }
                      }

                      ProfileSubmithandler=()=>{
                        alert(this.state.uType + " " + this.state.AdminNavbutton)


                      }
                      componentDidMount() {
                        this.readUserData();
                      };

                      readUserData=()=> {
                        userstype= 'users/'+ firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/userType'

                        firebase.database().ref(userstype).once('value').then(snapshot => {
                            this.setState({ uType: snapshot.val() }) // notworking and not updating uType
                            alert(snapshot.val()) //working Properly
                        })

                        }
                        emailid=()=>{
                        }


                      render() {
                        return (

                          <View style={styles.container}>
                            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Taams</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.edition}>Developer's Edition</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.titleText}>Home</Text>
                            <Text>Alpha 0.0.0.1</Text>
                         {
                          this.state.AdminNavbutton &&
                            <RkButton onPress = {()=>this.ProfileSubmithandler()}>
                              <Text style={styles.LoginButtonText}>Submit</Text>
                            </RkButton>



                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate(this.state.AdminNavbutton)}><Text style={styles.signinButton}>Profile</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                        }
                          </View>
                        );
                      }
                    }
```

Comment: upgraded my React and React native versions that fixed my problems